# Angular typescript how to flatten nested array to find only object with certain condition

Tags: javascript

I have the following array object. I would like to flatten the array to get only object with names containing 'Martin'

Source Array:

```
[
    {
        "id": 302,
        "name": "David Martin",
        "subordinates": [
            {
                "id": 265,
                "name": "Martin Regan",
            },
            {
                "id": 300,
                "name": "William Baker",
            },
            {
                "id": 301,
                "name": "Anthony Mazzarino",
                "subordinates": [
                    {
                        "id": 11245,
                        "name": "Martin Lozano",
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        "id": 10441,
        "name": "Martin Delage De Luget"    
    }
]
```

Expected Result:

```
[
    {
        "id": 302,
        "userGuid": "66d6fd24-0e22-4384-9181-f72c4e81cefd",
        "name": "David Martin"  
    },
    {
        "id": 265,
        "name": "Martin Regan",
    },
    {
        "id": 11245,
        "name": "Martin Lozano",
    }   
]
```

Comment: Given the number of questions about flattening arrays already on SO it would be helpful to know [in your question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) what you'd already looked at and why those solutions didn't work. You've labelled this as angular + typescript, other than adding a couple of appropriate typings, how do you expect the answer to be different from one based on JavaScript? (might help find related questions)

Answer (score 0):

Recursion is always an easy solution in these kind of cases:

```
flatElements = (array, keyword) => {

  // Recursive function
  const traverse = (subArray, acc = []) => {

    subArray.forEach(element => {

      const {id, name, subordinates} = element;

      // If object with certain condition push it in the resulting acc 
      if (element.name.contains(keyword)) {
        acc.push({id, name});
      }

      // If subordinates exist, traverse them deeply
      if (subordinates) {
          traverse(subordinates, acc);
      }

    });

    // Return accumulator
    return acc;

  }
  
  return traverse(array, []);
  
}
```